# Python selenium how to hidden webdriver detection

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, webdriver

I trying navigate a web site using automation steps with selenium 
When I run the script and I check the source-code. I found this

```
<html webdriver="true">
```

And this code blocks the selenium script. I think this is a javascript code that detect the webdriver.

How can I hidden my webdriver to be undetectable?

Comment: I don't think you can do such thing! You are loading a webdriver and you expect not to be a webdriver? BTW, maybe you can perform this bby removing `webdriver` attribute from `html` tag; see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22711441/remove-readonly-attributes-in-selenium-webdriver?answertab=active#tab-top). But I'm 99% sure that there is no way to prevent this attribute in start-up.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi. The full path may be like C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.xpi and once opened, look at \content\dommessenger.js line 97. There's no real need of this tag to make it work. It's easy if you edit the files onthefly with 7zip rather than extracting them.